# Rails: retrieving image from Facebook after Omniauth login with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I setup Facebook login with Devise and omniauth with these instructions https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

The Devise wiki gives some instructions for getting facebook info from the hash stored in this variable `request.env['omniauth.auth']` See bottom for the hash.

For example, Devise wiki has these two methods for the `User.rb` model

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.extra.raw_info
  if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
    user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"]

      end
    end
  end
```

So, using the hash below, I added the following to those two methods to get the name and image

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.extra.raw_info
  if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
    user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20], :name => data.name, :image => access_token.info.image) #I added access_token.info.image based on first answer
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"]
        user.name = data["name"]
        user.image = access_token.info.image  #i changed this based on first answer below

      end
    end
  end
```

Then in my view, I added the following to show the user name and image

```
<p>Name:<%= user.name %></p>
 <p>Image: <%= image_tag user.image %>
```

However, only the name is showing. No image.

In my database, I have a `name` and an `image` column. The name from Facebook is being stored, but the image column says 'nil'

Any ideas how I can get the image to work?

**Hash stored in** `request.env['omniauth.auth']` https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb#L31-47

```
   info do
        prune!({
          'nickname' => raw_info['username'],
          'email' => raw_info['email'],
          'name' => raw_info['name'],
          'first_name' => raw_info['first_name'],
          'last_name' => raw_info['last_name'],
          'image' => "#{options[:secure_image_url] ? 'https' : 'http'}://graph.facebook.com/#{uid}/picture?type=square",
          'description' => raw_info['bio'],
          'urls' => {
            'Facebook' => raw_info['link'],
            'Website' => raw_info['website']
          },
          'location' => (raw_info['location'] || {})['name'],
          'verified' => raw_info['verified']
        })
      end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The image can be found at `env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["image"]`. So in your case, `access_token.info.image`.

If you want to take a good look at the hash of nested hashes returned and see for yourself where everything is, put this as the first line of your callback controller:

```
render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
```

EDIT: Ok, so here's what you need to do:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(omniauth)
  if user = User.find_by_email(omniauth.info.email)
    if omniauth.info.image.present?
      user.update_attribute(:image, omniauth.info.image)
    end
    user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    User.create!(:email => omniauth.info.email,
                 :name => omniauth.info.name,
                 :image => omniauth.info.image,
                 :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
  end
end
```

As for the other method, if I'm not mistaken, it should look like this:

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  super.tap do |user|
    if omniauth = session["devise.facebook_data"]
      user.email = omniauth.info.email
      user.name = omniauth.info.name
      user.image = omniauth.info.image
    end
  end
end
```

But when is this method used? It's used by Devise when something goes wrong when creating your user. Imagine that the authentication provider doesn't give you an email (Twitter, for example, does this), what can you do? Well, you can redirect the user to your sign up page where he can complete the signup process. But if you redirect the user, you lose the data received by the oauth. The solution is to put this data into the session.

So in your controller, you should have something like:

```
if user.save
  sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

Another problem, however, is that most of the times the data returned by the authentication provider is too big to fit in the session, so we have to pick exactly what we want to put in the session. Since you are only getting a name and an image, you can trim the extra info like so:

```
session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"].except('extra')
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about the viewing the hash. I see why it should be access_token.info.image but still can't get it to work. In the two methods in the User model, I did :image => access_token.info.image AND user.image = access_token.info.image (see updated OP).. However, in the second method new_with_session, it's getting "raw_info" rather than "info" so is that why image isn't available? do you know how I can change that method if I have to? Also, the image column in my database is still 'nil'. Not sure if it's supposed to be.

Comment: weird. Got it to work, but when I added Carrierwave (using ryan bates instructions) to allow non-facebook users to add image, the facebook image no longer worked. The first facebook signup has the image link stored in database but it's not showing anymore (I'm getting a nil error <p>Image: <%= image_tag user.image%> on this) but also after installing carrier wave, i tried another facebook signup with a different account, and it's not saving the url for the image to the database. The second facebook login has 'nil' for the database image. This is different question but if you know answer ...thx

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used Carrierwave, so I wouldn't know. I think you're confusing one thing though: when logging in with Facebook, you are only saving a link to the image, not the image itself. With Carrierwave you are uploading an image. You may have mixed up something. Ask another question here on SO, maybe someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: @Michael, did you ever find a way to make it work with Carrierwave?

Comment: @cgf I got this work - carrierwave allows for remote image urls.  So where you see the following line pulled from accepted answer:

:image => omniauth.info.image,
will be changed to
:remote_image_url => omniauth.info.image, - where "image" is the name of your uploader.  So in my case this looked like the following:
:remote_avatar_url => omniauth.info.image.

Than simply add ":remote_avatar_url" to attr_accessible and you should be good to go!

Comment: i love you and you answer.  if we use only one auth, can we just delete the new_with_session function?

Comment: If you are certain that the authentication provider you are using will always return enough user data to create a valid user record, then you can remove the `new_with_session` method. You can also remove the `else` branch that redirects the user to another page.