# Persist Facebook profile picture url on Rails 3

Tags: devise, omniauth, facebook-authentication, rails-3.1

I added Facebook authentication to my Rails 3 app according to this [tutorial](http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2012/01/20/adding-facebook-auth-to-rails-3-1-app/), and it's working great.

Now I want to display the user's name and profile picture, once he/she has logged in to the app using Facebook. I tried following the solution given here:
[Rails: retrieving image from Facebook after Omniauth login with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848543/rails-retrieving-image-from-facebook-after-omniauth-login-with-devise)

But then, I get the following error:

"Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, image"

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set

```
attr_accessible :name, :image
```

in the appropriate model.

Comment: Please @humairatasnim mark the answer as valid if it worked for you.