# Save facebook profile picture in my own server using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, carrierwave

I am working in an rails application in which there are a option to signup user using his facebook account.

Now I am using OmniAuth gem to authenticate user from facebook. And saving/uploading user's profile photo using carrierwave.

But I can not upload and save users profile photo in my server, when I getting the user's profile photo link using **OmniAuth**.

I want not use remote link for profile photo, as any time it will be changed from facebook or my user will want to change his profile photo in my website.

**Please help me that how I save in my server the user's profile photo from this facebook link?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: retrieving image from Facebook after Omniauth login with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848543/rails-retrieving-image-from-facebook-after-omniauth-login-with-devise). Check the comments on the accepted answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I use carrierwave to accomplish that:

1. Add this to your Gemfile, then '$ bundle install'

   ```
   #for image processing/uploading
   gem 'carrierwave'
   gem 'mini_magick'
   ```
2. Generate a new uploader for the image files '$ rails g uploader Image', you can config this one as you like; I configured mine to store a thumbnail version in addition to the original, like so:

   ```
    #You need ImageMagick library to use this
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    #This stores a thumbnail version and the original
    #You need ImageMagick
    version :thumb do
       process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
    end

    #this validates file extensions
    def extension_whitelist
       %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
   ```
3. I used a separate model to store images in my db, but you can also store the image reference directly to the user model, either way, you just need to add a column with data type string to the model where you want to store the image reference. Something like '$ rails g migration AddImageToUserTable image:string' once you have it, add this to that model file:

   ```
     #this tells Carrierwave to use the image attribute in the
     #model to store the file reference
     mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
   ```
4. Finally (if you stored the reference in your user model) you can have something like this inside your user model file where you store the facebook responce:

   ```
   def self.create_from_provider_data(provider_data)    
     where(provider: provider_data.provider, uid: provider_data.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|  
       user.remote_picture_url = provider_data.info.image
       user.username = provider_data.info.name
       user.email = provider_data.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
       user.oauth_token = provider_data.credentials.token
       user.oauth_expires_at = provider_data.credentials.expires_at
       user.save!        
     end
   end
   ```

I was 6 years late xD, but hope this helps someone. :)